# Scrapy: saving cookies between invocations

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Is there a way to preserve cookies between invocations of a scrapy crawler?  The purpose - the site requires log in, and then maintains the session via cookies.  I'd rather reuse the session than re-login every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the docs about cookies.

[FAQ entry](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/faq.html#does-scrapy-manage-cookies-automatically)

[CookiesMiddleware](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#cookies-mw)

Alternatively you can send `Request` objects with cookies managed by yourself (you can read cookies from `Response` objects' head).

[About Request and Response objects](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html)

Comment: Yes, I've seen that.  What I would essentially like is CookiesMiddleware which would store its state on the disk at the end of execution and at the start of execution read it, if available.  I've looked at the source at github and there is no support for that, sadly.  But I can always extend it, I guess.  Maybe it's the easiest thing to do in my case.

Comment: Yes, you can implement your custom solution, and in this case this would be the way you have to go. Scrapy cannot cover all cases but gives the possibility to extend the tool if it does not fit your purposes.

Comment: Fair enough, I have no problem with that.  Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

There is now (2023) an open source package, [scrapy-cookies](https://github.com/scrapedia/scrapy-cookies), that will save cookies like you wanted.

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Comment: No, I had the same question as OP. Why do you ask?

Comment: the documentation for it is terrible and hasn't been updated in years