# Scrapy - User session timeout occurs and logouts user while scraping a website

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

Why does the user is being loggedout, while in the middle of scraping? I can not share my code, i just wanted to know why does this behaviour occurs -

- Is it because of cookies? ( I have not passed any cookies manually, as scrapy handles the cookies by default)
- Is it that certain headers are missing in requests?(I have not passed any headers explictly for requests)
- Or is it due to any other reasons?
- If it is because of cookies, how can i pass them for each requests?
- If it is because of headers, what are the most important headers that need to be passed for each requests?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree it's due to the expiration of the session, after a lot of research, the proxy service which I was using was not maintaining the session while scraping the site.

When looking upon all proxy service providers, provide a provision to maintain a session while using the proxy, by using this one can avoid getting logged out of a site while scraping.

Answer (score 2):

If you log in, yes you need to handle the cookies, For more information about the cookies, please look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31649077/4527978).

It can be also because your session is expired on the site, so when you have this problem you need to re-log on the site.

For the headers, you need to inspect the network and see which headers you need for your requests.